# Highcharts tooltip auto-resize on content change

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, highcharts

I have a Highcharts graph with tooltips that on hover display a loading spinner and fetch via AJAX some data from the server to display. When the request completes the data is put into a `span` in the tooltip using jQuery, but the new content overflows as the tooltip doesn't resize. Here's my SCSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    span {
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Is there a setting or API function I can use to either have the tooltip automatically resize when its content changes, or force a redraw? Alternatively, is there some CSS I can use to make this work?

N.B. I can set the size of the tooltip manually by setting the height/width of the `span` above.

Comment: Which tooltip options do you have in your chart definition?

Comment: `useHtml: true` and `followPointer: true`. Formatter returns a string and a loading spinner, and fires off the AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to disable default tooltip and use full responsive / HTML div (use media queries), which will be toolip.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function (e) {
                        $('#tooltip').html('Point value: ' + this.y).css({
                            top: e.target.plotY - 15,
                            left: e.target.plotX
                        }).show();

                    },
                    mouseOut: function (e) {
                        $('#tooltip').hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gL7j6bzq/2/